# Как добавить BB коды в свою форму?

Tags: forms, html

Необходимо в админку простого сайта добавить BB коды. Гугл не спасает, везде линки на BB коды для юкоза -_- ни 1 нормальной статьи не нашёл, как это сделать. Мой уровень пока мал, чтобы придумать, как это сделать самому. Ткните пожалуйста, где можно нормально почитать про это

Comment: А [тут](http://irbis-team.com/15/18?PHPSESSID=97a8cafdac2ef9a82fa4c28a9832ee35) смотрели? Ребята с ирбиса постарались.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем вдуплил вопрос, но отвечу на то что вдуплил:
просто создаете некоторые условные значения (например типа [b] и [/b]) и при выводе на странице наменяете (str_replace() кажись) на тэги (например <b> и </b>). Так же со смайлами и т.п.

Google все еще рулит. Но так как сам еще эту задачу не решал поделюсь
http://www.askdev.ru/jquery/4530/Обертывание-выделенного-текста-тегами/

вот на спех собраное

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
(function($) {
   $.fn.wrapSelected = function(open, close) {
     return this.each(function() {
       var textarea = $(this);
       var value = textarea.val();
       var start = textarea[0].selectionStart;
       var end = textarea[0].selectionEnd;
       textarea.val(
         value.substr(0, start) + 
         open + value.substring(start, end) + close + 
         value.substring(end, value.length)
       );  }); };})(jQuery);
$("#but").click(function(){
$("textarea#myTextArea").wrapSelected("[b]", "[/b]");
});
   });  
</script>

<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea><input type="button" id="but">
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы при выделении слова, например, в форме и нажатии на кнопку, это слово обособлялось этими самыми необходимыми тегами? как на форумах, тобеж

Comment: Ответ дополнен в ответе выше :))))

Comment: блин, я в jquery не шарю нифига, хотелось бы понимать то, что я использую...) я пока читаю, то, что мне ниже дали)
без скриптов это не реализовать, да? планировал ведь начать учиться скриптам...настало видимо время :))

Comment: Естественно пора, раз уж дорос до таких задач. :)))